# How can I compile a Scala and LWJGL3 application?

Tags: scala, classpath, lwjgl

I'm having a lot of trouble compiling a Scala program with LWJGL3. I suspect that I either don't understand Scala's import statement correctly, or I don't understand Scala's classpath correctly. I've placed the LWJGL3 Nightly download in an `org` folder at my project root. This is the error `scalac` gives me:

```
Minimum.scala:1: error: object opengl is not a member of package org.lwjgl
import org.lwjgl.opengl._
                 ^
Minimum.scala:3: error: object glfw is not a member of package org.lwjgl
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW._
                 ^
Minimum.scala:4: error: object opengl is not a member of package org.lwjgl
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11._
                 ^
Minimum.scala:5: error: object system is not a member of package org.lwjgl
import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil._
                 ^
```

(Plus lots of `error: not found: value _______` errors because it couldn't find the various functions.)

Here's my code (in Minimum.scala at the project root):

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl._

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW._
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11._
import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil._


object Minimum {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        glfwInit()

        long windowHandle = glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "Hello, World!", NULL, NULL)
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(windowHandle)

        GL.createCapabilities()
        glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)

        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(windowHandle)) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
            glfwSwapBuffers(windowHandle)
            glfwPollEvents()
        }

        glfwDestroyWindow(windowHandle)
    }
}
```

I've also tried these import statements instead, which were suggested [here](https://github.com/dlpatri/scala-lwjgl/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/example/Main.scala):

```
import org.lwjgl._, glfw._, opengl._
import Callbacks._, GLFW._, GL11._

import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil._
```

Finally, I'm compiling with this command:

```
scalac -classpath ".;org/lwjgl/*;org/lwjgl-egl/*;org/lwjgl-glfw/*;org/lwjgl-jawt/*;org/lwjgl-jemalloc/*;org/lwjgl-lmdb/*;org/lwjgl-nanovg/*;org/lwjgl-nfd/*;org/lwjgl-nuklear/*;org/lwjgl-openal/*;org/lwjgl-opencl/*;org/lwjgl-opengl/*;org/lwjgl-opengles/*;org/lwjgl-ovr/*;org/lwjgl-par/*;org/lwjgl-sse/*;org/lwjgl-stb/*;org/lwjgl-tinyfd/*;org/lwjgl-vulkan/*;org/lwjgl-xxhash/*" Minimum.scala
```

Which I've tried numerous variations on including omitting the `*`, adding `*.jar`, moving the lwjgl libraries to another folder, giving just the `org/` directory rather than the complete list, and replacing the `;` with `:`. This is essentially the command I used to compile a nearly identical Java application, which worked perfectly.

Does anyone know how I can get my program to compile?

Comment: I'd suggest using sbt rather than manually grabbing jars and trying to manually assemble an appropriate classpath